# Can I put an app to TestFlight with only appStoreConnect Account

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight

I need to upload a build of my app to test flight, Now my client has given me an admin role in app store connect only and didn't add my apple id in developer.apple.com.

Can I upload the app to test flight?

If yes, How can I do that?
If no, what is the next procedure I should follow?

I am confused as in why the developer portal and app store connect have been separated and need to know about it too.

P.S: This is the first time I am uploading app, so bear with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Login in https://developer.apple.com
2. Tap on Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
3. In the left side menu , under Identifiers tap on App id option 
   Add your app there with unique name. (com.yourappname.domain)
   Add certificates and provisioning profiles.
   Take ref from this link https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev34e9bbb5a
4. Login to iTunes connect
5. My apps, your added app will be visible there.
6. After all the setup upload your app on app store.
7. Go to the App store connect , your uploaded app will visible under activity section.
8. Add testers for testflight .
9. Once your app completes review from tesflight a notification to all added testers will be sent with a build link.
10. Remember Uploading app on testflight is same as uploading app on app store.
    but app will be not uploaded on app store untill you Submit app for Review. Tesflight only make the build available to added testers.

Answer (score 0):

you do need a Paid Developer Account to put your app on TestFlight or the App Store. if you have you can.

just follow the steps below
https://medium.com/@dmathewwws/steps-to-put-your-app-on-testflight-and-then-the-ios-app-store-10a7996411b1